# BasicDataSource is overridden by non-compatible bean instance of type UrlDecodingDataSource

Tags: java, spring, cloud-foundry

I tried to expose my Spring Restful web api to Pivotal Cloud Foundary, I successfully connected with Pivotal MySql database, in Local it is working fine but when I push the war in `PCF` it throws an exception

```
    nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Bean method
 SpringBeanContainer.dataSource called as bean reference for type
 [org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource] but overridden by non-compatible
 bean instance of type [org.cloudfoundry.reconfiguration.org.springframework.cloud.service.relational.UrlDecodingDataSource].
```

I am new to cloud and i don't have an idea much about it, it seems that `UrlDecodingDataSource` tries to override something, due to this my `sessionFactory` is not able to create as bean.

**Detailed Log**

```
      [OUT] org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
     Error creating bean with name 'loginController': Unsatisfied dependency
     expressed through field 'userDetailService'; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'userDetailService': Unsatisfied dependency
 expressed through field 'uddDao'; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error
 creating bean with name 'userDetailDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed
 through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
 with name 'sessionFactory' defined in
 com.javarnd.cc.configuration.SpringBeanContainer: Bean instantiation via
 factory method failed; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate
 [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Factory method
 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Bean method SpringBeanContainer.dataSource
 called as bean reference for type [org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource]
 but overridden by non-compatible bean instance of type [org.cloudfoundry.reconfiguration.org.springframework.cloud.service.relational.UrlDecodingDataSource].
```

**DataSource snippet in my SpringBeanContainer**

```
@Bean // Simple Bean Defination in XML
    public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty(DRIVER_CLASS));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty(URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty(USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty(PASSWORD));
        return dataSource;
    }
```

Kindly help me to resolve this or sugge

Comment: I'd recommend making the return type a DataSource interface instead of a BasicDataSource concrete implementation.  Is there an @Configuration annotation on the class with this method?

Comment: yes I annotated the class with @Configuration

Comment: You should prefer the interface type as the return.

Comment: Ok, I did the same,but it still not working, still same exception arose

Comment: I'd look at your pooling implementation next.

Comment: It worked like charm, thank you so much, I clean the project, update the project and then generate the war again, finally uploaded